# Draw a (2D/3D) graph given the adjancecy matrix and the corrdinates of the nodes with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I am trying to plot a graph given the adjancecy matrix and the coordinates of the nodes with this code below, using matplotlib. Yet when I vizualize the graph, it's not the same as the adjancecy matrix, and mainly some edges are missing. Any insights? 
NB: for now I am only plotting 2D Graph so my Z are 0, so if you have any other idea on how to do so (maybe with networkx) I'll appreciate your help too

```
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
import numpy as np
#from numpy import sin, cos, sqrt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri
#from sklearn import preprocessing
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d as plt3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update({'figure.max_open_warning': 0})
plt.switch_backend('agg')

def draw_surface( points_coord, adj):
  '''points_coord.shape: (num_points, coord=3),
    adj.shape:(num_points,num_points)'''
  name= 'img'  
  fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
  # Plot the surface.
  ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')
  #ax.plot_trisurf(triang, z,  cmap=cm.jet)#cmap=plt.cm.CMRmap)

  x = points_coord[:,0]
  y = points_coord[:,1]
  if len(points_coord) == 3:
    z = points_coord[:,2]
  else:
    z = np.zeros_like(points_coord[:,0])  

  max_val = np.max(adj)
  list_edges = []
  #plot lines from edges
  for i in range(adj.shape[0]):
    for j in range(i,adj.shape[1]):
      if adj[i][j]:
        line = plt3d.art3d.Line3D([x[i],x[j]], [y[i],y[j]], [z[i],z[j]], \
          linewidth=0.4, c="black", alpha = round( adj[i,j], 4 ))
        list_edges.append((i,j))
        ax.add_line(line)

  ax.scatter(x,y,z, marker='.', s=15, c="blue", alpha=0.6)
  #ax.view_init(azim=25)
  plt.axis('off')
  plt.show()
  plt.savefig(name+'.png', dpi=120)
  plt.clf()
```

Comment: You didn't add any test data???  Maybe your adjacency matrix isn't symmetric and you need to test `if adj[i][j] >0 or adj[j][i] >0:` ? Maybe also leave out the alpha in the line drawing, just in case it would be zero for the wrong values (maybe it can get negative)? Please only use `if adj[i][j]:` in case `adj` would be a boolean matrix.

Comment: That's true My matrix was not symmetric ! Thanks

Comment: Hello again, should the coordinates be integers? because i ve been giving random coordinates in [0,1] and it works, but then I noticed that the plot doesnt really look random so I wondered maybe it s not taking the given coordinates into account